# Using rules to secure certain key=val pairs as public or private VS having separate public and private paths

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to determine how I should organise some user data that can be a mix of both public and private entities. The entities in question are Activity Stream events. Followers of the user can see their Activity Stream events - however the user can mark certain categories of events as 'public' or 'private' and therefore not share them with their followers.

One way to do it would be to create `activity_streams_private` and `activity_streams_public` paths that have respective security rules and then a Cloud Function could handle what is added and removed from `activity_streams_public` based on how the user updates their privacy settings.

```
"rules": {
    "activity_streams_settings": {
        "$userID": {
            "read": "auth.uid == $userID",
            "write": "auth.uid == $userID"
        }
    },
    "activity_streams_private": {
        // Users only write Activity Stream events here.
        "$userID": {
            "read": "auth.uid == $userID",
            "write": "auth.uid == $userID"
        }
    },
    "activity_streams_public": {
        "$userID": {
            // Every user can read public activity stream data
            "read": "auth.uid != null",

            // Only Cloud Functions can update what appears in
            // a user's public activity stream by determining
            // if an activity added to activity_streams_private
            // is public or private using the
            // activity_stream_settings data. Every settings
            // change would cause the Cloud Function to read
            // this entire subtree of data and write/delete a lot.
            "write": false,
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep all a user's public and private Activity Stream events in a path like `activity_streams` and then have query based security rules that only allow a follower to query Activity Stream events with a `public=true` property. This would still require the user's device (or a Cloud Function) to update all items in `activity_streams` to include/exclude the `public=true` property every time a privacy setting is changed.

```
"rules": {
    "activity_streams_settings": {
        "$userID": {
            "read": "auth.uid == $userID",
            "write": "auth.uid == $userID"
        }
    },
    "activity_streams": {
        "$userID": {
            // Only children with the 'visibility=public' property
            // can be read (or the owner of the activity stream).
            // This method will mean that the ID of each Activity
            // Stream event will be in the form of:
            // timestampDescending_eventUUID so that the events
            // are automatically sorted by newest first.
            "read": "auth.uid == $userID || (auth.uid != null && query.orderBy = 'visibility' && query.equalTo = 'public')",

            // Users can append Activity Stream events with a
            // preset visibility property (public or private)
            // but a Cloud Function will change the visibility
            // property on events if a user changes their settings.
            "write": "auth.uid == $userID",
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I'm asking what the drawbacks and benefits of each method are. Do query-based security rules slow down read speeds? Is either solution more scalable as the user-base grows? In a short ~5 minute session, a user will generate anywhere between 25 to 75 activity stream events.

My concern with doing `activity_streams_public` is that the writes may cause scalability issues at ~1M users even with infrequent privacy settings changes. Thoughts?

Comment: This is a bit broad.  Also a bit difficult to visualize, without actual rules and database structure to look at.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the question with hopefully some more clarification. Is that enough to explain the question of which method scales better and is considered as 'idiomatic NoSQL'?

Comment: The drawback of your second approach is that you can't query for only the public information. Having separate top-level nodes for the public and private information is the only way to implement this in a way that also allows users to query the public information. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891762/firebase-security-rules-public-vs-private-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hmmm, I thought if a follower ran a query like `orderBy('visibility').equalTo('public')` then it would allow someone to query just the public activities in the stream as the rule allows this query?    



`"read": "auth.uid == $userID || (auth.uid != null && query.orderBy = 'visibility' && query.equalTo = 'public')"`



    I could have sworn I recently read that this was possible. I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: That means each child node in the stream is either entirely public or entirely private. Is that indeed the case? If so, I misunderstood the structure you're aiming for.

Comment: So, under `/activity_streams/[userID]` you would have a list of `activity` objects for a particular user. Each `activity` object contains, amongst other things, a property called `visibility` that can be either set to `public` or `private`. So when one of my followers queries _my_ `/activity_streams/[myUserID]` then they would use the query `orderBy('visibility').equalTo('public')` which would retrieve only those objects which have a public visibility, leaving out any others that have a private visibility. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding if this is even possible. I thought it was with query rules