# Unable to write to realtime database but able to read when using $uid match parameter in authentication rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a website where users can upgrade to a premium account. The page looks like this.

[image: subscribe page]

When they click the red subscribe button it lets the user know they have been successful. The subscriber data is then added to the subscribers collection in my database. Here is an example [image: subscribe database collection]

This is all secured with authentication rules to prevent anyone seeing who subscribed to my website.

**Problem**

When I have my rules configured like below then I am unable to click the red subscribe button.

```json
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      ".indexOn": "username",
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true 
         
    },
"subscribe":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
      }
```

When I swap the read & write then I am able to click the red subscribe button and it all works fine.

```json
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      ".indexOn": "username",
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
         
    },
"subscribe":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
      }
```

I dont understand why subscribing doesnt work when I add the uid requirement in my rules for writing but it works when I swap them around. The database has not changed so surely both conditions should behave the same?

**Possible theory**

Maybe its because of the way my database is structured currently. Everything is public and there are no private vs public collections. I am not sure though.
I saw this mentioned in these answer threads:

•   [Firebase: How to structure public/private user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data)

•   [Firebase Security Rules: Public vs. Private Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891762/firebase-security-rules-public-vs-private-data)

Here is a sample of my "users" collection for reference.
[image: users collection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashok has explained about the set of rules behavior.
Let me clarify further for your comment on "read" = "seeing" webpage.

```
{
  "subscribe": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to point out the $uid right below the subscribe key. This $uid means giving this position as variable to check and name it "$uid"

```
{
  "subscribe": {
    "0": {
      "age": 24,
      "email": "ameraz@email.com",
      "name": "Alex Meraz"
    },
    "1": {
      "age": 21,
      "email": "mrafi@email.com",
      "name": "Mohammed Rafi"
    },
    "b8eVaJs1JMVjRJQ2X3vE0PHl70B3": {
      "abcabc": "aasd"
    }
  }
}
```

Now lets say my User UID is "b8eVaJs1JMVjRJQ2X3vE0PHl70B3", i can see my data only as

```
{
    "abcabc": "aasd"
}
```

this is because i got

".read": "auth !== null && **auth.uid === $uid"**

Meaning auth from auth module not null and auth.uid equals to $uid key which is iterated matching from the array (last item key).

Now for write condition

".write": "auth != null && **auth.token.email_verified == true"**

Meaning allow any user that is authenticated and email verified. So $uid not used here, any verified email user can do anything with existing or non-existing key.

***Previous entry just shows you the working logic (which probably has risk of accessing other people subscription), now lets dive in to the incorrect conditions.***

".read": "auth != null && **auth.token.email_verified == true**",

This will give you access to all the items (with key 0, 1, and b8eVaJs1JMVjRJQ2X3vE0PHl70B3) if the logged in user email verified.

".write": "auth !== null && **auth.uid === $uid"**,

This will only give write access to the already existing one (modify only to item b8eVaJs1JMVjRJQ2X3vE0PHl70B3), you can not add more item to the sibling of this key, you have access only inside this key.

Which is:

```
{
    "abcabc": "aasd"
}
```

Comment: Thanks arifnpm. This is making much more sense now. So it seems the reason I cant write is because there was no data added to the collection (array) from the user in the first place. So there is nothing to write/modify, since the uid doesnt exist in the collection. That makes sense!

What about reading? Does reading just mean "pulling" data from the array. Just want to make sure I am not misintepreting reading as equivalent to just "viewing" a webpage.

Comment: Almost correct, the reason you can't write (insert) is because you don't have permission to write to other key not belonging to the current user uid. If it is new, the data simply not existing in the current array of items so auth.uid === $uid" always becoming a "false". (actually there is a way to determine for existing data of old data or new data, please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data)

Comment: read and write in the rules is actually iteration of each item. the condition will be tested one by one, if the condition tested for the particular item become true, then the rule apply for that item (can read and/or can write).

Comment: thanks this clears up what write means and why I was unable to write. However I am still not clear on what reading means. Could you please clarify if reading has anything to do with being able to view a webpage or not?

Comment: For firebase realtime database no, it is only the permission to read that particular data item. But, it might affect the website view when coded to do so in the client side javscript (html or js file) or in the backend (firebase functions ).

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Security Rules you've provided are controlling access to a "subscribe" node where each user's subscription status is stored under their unique user ID ("$uid"). The rules are designed to allow users to subscribe to something based on certain conditions.

Let's break down the rules you provided:

First Set of Rules:

```json
{
  "subscribe": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

In this set of rules, you have the following conditions:

1. `.read` condition: The user must be authenticated (`auth != null`) and have their email verified to read the subscription status.
2. `.write` condition: The user must be authenticated (`auth !== null`) and their UID must match the "$uid" in order to write (subscribe).

Second Set of Rules (Swapped Conditions):

```json
{
  "subscribe": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified == true"
    }
  }
}
```

In this set of rules, you've swapped the conditions:

1. `.read` condition: The user must be authenticated (`auth !== null`) and their UID must match the "$uid" to read the subscription status.
2. `.write` condition: The user must be authenticated (`auth != null`) and have their email verified to write (subscribe).

The issue you described is that the first set of rules doesn't allow you to click the red subscribe button, but the second set of rules does.

The most likely explanation for this behavior is related to the user's authentication state. In the first set of rules, you require the user to be both authenticated and have their email verified to read but only require authentication to write. In the second set of rules, you require email verification to write but only authentication to read.

If the user is already authenticated but hasn't verified their email, the first set of rules will prevent them from reading (subscribing) but allow them to write (subscribe), while the second set of rules will allow them to read but not write.

To resolve this issue and ensure consistency in your rules, you can choose the set of rules that aligns better with your application's authentication and email verification flow. If you want to enforce email verification for both reading and writing, you should use the second set of rules. If you want to allow authenticated users to write (subscribe) even if they haven't verified their email, you can use the first set of rules. The choice depends on your specific security requirements and how you want to handle user access in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ashok. You mentioned if the user is authenticated but hasn't verified then the first set of rules will prevent reading but allow writing. In my case, the user is authenticated and verified. Yet they are still unable to write to the database. 

In the second set of rules they can write because they are authenticated and verified. However If the $uid rule is acting the same as in the first set of rules,shouldn't they be unable to "see" the webpage? I dont know if my understanding of reading is incorrect? I imagine "read" is equievalent to"seeing" the webpage.

Comment: Yeah read means you can view things on webpage